# Why this Linq is returning null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-4.0

I have a method to authenticate my users, but it returns `user = null` even if I have records in my table.

```
public bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
   var user = GetSingleRow(c => c.Email.Equals(username) && c.Password.Equals(password) && IsActive);  

   if(user !=null && user.Id > 0)
   {
    // my statements
   }
}
```

Class & Method Implementation :

```
public partial class UserAccount :IRepository<UserAccount>
{
    private static readonly MeriRanchiDataContext Context;
    public UserAccount GetSingleRow(Func<UserAccount, bool> criteria)
    {
       return Context.UserAccounts.Where(criteria).SingleOrDefault();
       //tried this also: return Context.UserAccounts.SingleOrDefault(criteria);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really have plaintext passwords in your database? Also, are you aware that because you're using delegates instead of expression trees, this will be fetching *all* the user accounts and applying the predicate locally?

Comment: I am storing plain text passwords in my database.

Comment: @JonSkeet ""Also, are you aware that because you're using delegates instead of expression trees, this will be fetching all the user accounts and applying the predicate locally?"" Is this a wrong approach to use predicates ???

Comment: Please do not store plaintext passwords... Please read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: Why -1 ?? Does not belong to programming or anything missing. I need suggesstions and help on the issue i am getting.. not on the architecture and storage of my app. If you guys truly want to help then please go on, else do downvote just for the sake of good programming approach and as an active SO member. Keep such guys your away from my questions..

Comment: You just have `IsActive`. Shouldn't it be `c.IsActive`? Unless maybe `IsActive` is a class variable?

Comment: @AmitRanjan: Yes, you should use an `Expression<Func<UserAccount, bool>>` instead. But as per everyone else, *don't* store passwords in plain text. If this is for a production system, please edit your question with the site so everyone knows to avoid signing up...

Comment: @AmitRanjan: You clearly *do* need advice on the storage of your app, if you're storing passwords in plain text. Are your users aware that you're doing so, and that any attacker who gets in will be able to find out their passwords which (sadly) they may be using elsewhere? If this is only a "toy" project, you should say so up-front - although I would suggest you should still store authentication information in a more secure fashion.

Comment: As for -1... I didn't downvote the question, but I can understand anyone who did. You say there are records in the table, but we have no idea whether they're records which match the incoming username and password, and records for *active* users...

Comment: For all that's holy, don't store passwords as plaintext. Some people might have just downvoted you *just* for that. But it's still a pretty bad question, so I'd understand the downvote.

Comment: Guys... this is an internal project of mine. Intranet based. I too know plain text passwords are bad idea. Generally I use ManagedAES algorithm to encrypt and decrypt password. I dont follow any fancy encryptions, instead the framework had for us. I know its hacker proof thats why passwords is in plain text. Please do not panic guys, it matter or mine security. You guys be cool :). Anyways I found my culprit and block is working fine.

Comment: @BobHorn : xactly.. c was missing from there.

Comment: @AmitRanjan: You shouldn't be *encrypting* passwords - you should be *hashing* them in some form... a one way process. "I know its hacker proof" - sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: There's very little difference between encrypting a password and leaving it in plaintext. See: [CWE-257](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/257.html). Point is, passwords should **never** be stored in a recoverable format (encrypted passwords *are* recoverable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing your range variable (c) on IsActive. Do this:

```
var user = GetSingleRow(c => c.Email.Equals(username) && c.Password.Equals(password) && c.IsActive);
```